# DB Table structure for events and grouped related events

Tags: sql-server, database-design, calendar

I have a DB being used by a Triathlon Coach. The DB was already developed to store general health information about athletes and their results from specific endurance tests the Coach uses to measure their progress.

The thing is their training plans are handled at the time in excel, the guy creates the routines and sends an updated excel file to each client every 1 or 2 weeks.

I´m changing that and want to store it in the DB. I already checked all the posts regarding storing calendar events and DB table structure for such cases and have some specific questions based on the following.

And event (or training session) can be individual, lets say the coach wants you to do X training session on X day(simple no complications there). But there is another possibility where you can be training for an event (let's say a Marathon or Triathlon) so the guy has a general template of 20 weeks worth of training sessions waiting to be modified for the specific needs of a client.

I need to be able to record an individual training session to a guy's calendar or in the other hand given the date of his goal Marathon/Triathlon assign him 20 weeks of training sessions based on his event's race date.

Let's say a training session consists of:
Session Name:
Sport:
Duration:
target Heartrate:
Description:

What´s the best approach to store this type of info?

The coach wants to have a library of training sessions, a library of training plans (that consist of many training sessions based on a given date)

So lets say if the Triathlon is on X date all the training plan's training sessions will be assigned to dates relative to the event's date so the day before would be assigned to "event date -1" they before "event day -2" and so on until "event date - 20 weeks(in days)"

What could be the best approach to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into structuring relational data (looks like you could use data modeler/database developer), you could just add some additional columns for something like TargetPlan, TargetPlanDate and related columns for trainer/trainee assignments.  If you're using SQL Server to automatically upload/import from Excel spreadsheets, this may be your simplest solution for a quick fix which would allow you to run queries/reports.  The more you use a central data solution, the more requirements you'll have so maybe this can help you gradually get to a relational schema structure.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The thing is there's not much of an option for me here since it was required that way. :(

Comment: @TikalDog:   If changing the table to add columns is not an option, then there's no way to store the data.  The only option you have then is to work with the data you are given and run queries against the data that is available, calculating the columns dynamically. That sounds obvious, so if there's some other aspect to this I'm missing, please respond with additional details.